# How can I compare strings to an array to determine highest index value?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, compare

I have several strings that I need to compare with values in an array to determine which has the highest index number.  For example, the data looks like this:

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

v1 = "4"
v2 = "A"
v3 = "8"
```

How would I write it so that it would compare each value and return the fact that v2 is the winner based on the index number for A being 12?

Comment: (1) Your `array` is not an array of strings. (2) The character `”` cannot be used like you have. (3) It is not clear how the set of strings to be compared are defined.

Answer (score 2):

A short version:

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

target = [4, "A", 8]
target & array  #=> [4, "A", 8]
array  & target #=> [4, 8, "A"]

(array & target ).last #=> "A"

target = ["B", "C"]
(array & target ).last #=> nil
```

Comment: Nice one, Jaugar. I'm not sure if we know if `array` is sorted (the example is, but it's not stated), but if not, that's a trivial change.

Comment: I think the `array` is a sorted list. There was no clue to sort the `array` in the question, if so, sort the `array` first should be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
a = array.map(&:to_s)
  #=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

target = ["4", "A", "8"]
(target & a).empty? ? nil : a[target.map { |s| a.index(s) }.compact.max]
  #=> "A"

target = ["B", "C"]
(target & a).empty? ? nil : a[target.map { |s| a.index(s) }.compact.max]
  #=> nil
```

I have assumed that `array` may not be sorted.

Comment: The third part of the ternary construction can be simplified to `target.max_by{|s| a.index(s).to_i}`. If there is no need to consider that a string in `target` may be absent in `a`, then the whole answer would be `target.max_by{|s| a.index(s)}`.

Comment: Very clever! I didn't think that would work until I noticed the `.to_i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

v1 = "4"
v2 = "A"
v3 = "8"

array.reverse.map(&:to_s).find { |e| [v1, v2, v3].include?(e) }
# => "A"
```

or

```
array.reverse.map(&:to_s).find(&[v1, v2, v3].method(:include?))
# => "A"
```